# Asterisk HA and SIP registration

Tags: sip, asterisk, high-availability, pacemaker

I setup an Active/Passive cluster with Pacemaker/Corosync/DRBD. I wanted to make an Asterisk server HA. The solution works perfectly but when the service fails on one server and starts on another all registered SIP clients with the active server will be lost. And the passive server show nothing in the output of:

```
sip show peers
```

Until clients make a call or register again. One solution is to set the Registration rate on clients to 1 Min or so. Are there other options? For example integrating Asterisk with a DBMS helps to save this kind of state in a DB??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all doing clusters by non-expert is bad idea.

You can use realtime sip architecture, it save state in database. Complexity - average. Note, "sip show peers" for realtime also show nothing.

You can use memory duplicating cluster(some solution for xen exists) which will copy memory state from one server to other. Complexity - very complex.